# "stack" based iOS photo component?

Tags: ios, components

I like the look and feel of the H&M photo catalog component.
Does anybody know, if there exists a similar component (open source)?

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could tinker with iCarousel and get something close to that.

[image]